# regarding image editing

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, photoshop

I have a requirement where I need to erase a particular area of an image, but the constraint is that i shouldn't see white color in the area where I applied my eraser tool. The area where I used my eraser tool shouldn't look different from the rest of the image's background color.

For eg: 
<s>http://www.hdwallpapers.net/gallery/thumbnails/computer/computer_0099_lightbox.jpg</s>

here you see windows icon in the middle, I want to remove that icon alone. In icon's place I need background color in such a manner that it matches with the rest of the image.

Could you suggest the steps and tools which i can use to achieve the same. I have adobe photoshop at present. can that be done using photoshop. If not, please suggest the tool which does that.

Comment: shafi, this is not a programming related question.
You can use the clone stamp tool in photoshop to get the job done. You may have to apply the blur tool afterwards.
Remember that there is no way to exactly reproduce the background.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't do what you want perfectly.  Assuming it's a flattened image (just pixel data), that information under the logo just doesn't exist.

However, you can erase it using a traditional eraser tool and then use a **clone** tool to fake what the background *should* look like.

This isn't really a programming question so it doesn't belong here, but I hope I helped.